# Modify a function to make it work on a list and a list of lists

Tags: regex, r

Consider the following function:

```
getexpr = function(s,g)substring(s,g,g+attr(g,'match.length')-1)
```

When applied to a string and a list, the following works fine:

```
match = mapply(getexpr,single_string,list)
```

What if I wanted to apply the above to a list of strings and a list of lists instead?

Comment: Can you give an example of use. Have you looked at the `stringr` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No data offered for testing so I'll offer what I would have started with assuming the "list of strings" is named `lsingle_string` and the "list of lists" is named `llist` :

```
mapply( function(lstr, llis) {
         mapply( getexpr, s=lstr, g=llis) } , lsingle_string, llist)
```

Comment: +1 - can also do `mapply(mapply, lsingle_string, llist, MoreArgs = list(FUN = getexpr))`